# Difference in minutes from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I'm trying to obtain the total amount of time difference from two timestamp columns (datetime)

I currently have a **Table 1** setup like the following:

- `Time_Line_Down` => datetime
- `Time_Line_Ran` => datetime
- `Total_Downtime` => Computed column with formula:

  (case when [Time_Line_Down] IS NULL then NULL else CONVERT([varchar],case when [Time_Line_Ran] IS NULL then NULL else [Time_Line_Ran]-[Time_Line_Down] end,(108)) end)

Every time some conditions occur, I am copying those three columns (I have more columns but the problem is on this ones) into another **Table 2** originally setup like the following:

- `Time_Line_Down` => datetime
- `Time_Line_Ran` => datetime
- `Total_Downtime` => datetime

I then use an excel spreadsheet to "Get External Data" from SQL Server and use a pivot table to work with the data.

**Example**

- `Time_Line_Down` = 2015-02-20 12:32:40.000
- `Time_Line_Ran` = 2015-02-20 12:34:40.000
- `Total_Downtime` = 1900-01-01 00:02:00.000

**Desired Output**

I want the pivot table to be able to give me a Grand Total of downtime from all rows in that table

Let's say it was forty five hours, fifty minutes and thirty seconds of accumulated downtime it should read like (45:50:30)

**The problem**:

Even if I format the `Total_Downtime` column in the excel pivot table as `h:mm:ss` to read like this:

- `Total_Downtime` = 0:02:00

As rows accumulate and the Grand Total is calculated the "Date" part of the timestamp is messing the result is the total exceeds 24 hours

**What I have tried**

I changed the data type format of column `Total_Downtime` in **Table 2** to time(0) so that it won't send the "Date" part, only the "Time" part of the timestamp, it is working and reads out 00:02:00

But now all the values in my pivot table on excel for that column are 0:00:00 no matter what value is actually in the SQL table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would not change your datatype to time. It will be nearly impossible to determine time when the two cross a date barrier. You have only 3 data portions you care about do a datediff first for hours, then a datediff for minutes mod 60 to get the minute, and finally a datediff seconds mod 60 to get the seconds. Should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel time format `[h]:mm:ss` which can go beyond 24 hours.

Alternatively, you can use the SQL function `DATEDIFF` to get the total downtime in seconds, and then convert that to however you need to display it in Excel, e.g.

```
case when [Time_Line_Down] IS NULL then NULL else case when [Time_Line_Ran] IS NULL then NULL else datediff(ss, Time_Line_Ran, Time_Line_Down) end end
```

I don't think you need the `CASE` statements here, you can just use

```
datediff(ss, Time_Line_Ran, Time_Line_Down)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, changing the time format in excel didn't give the results I expected since now is showing values like 5774:11:47 .. I'm assuming is due to the "Date" part. I'm currently testing using the SQL function DATEDIFF like you and Sean Lange recommended, I will let you know the results. You are right, the case statement is just to not calculate the Total_Downtime if the time stamps are missing from the Time_Line_Ran and Time_Line_Down columns mostly due to my application.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help,

I went ahead an tried the function DATEDIFF as suggested, I changed **Table 1** computed column formula and **Table 2** Total_Downtime column data type to int. Once imported into excel this numeric value needed some extra calculations.

In principle is the best answer and should work for anyone trying to calculate the difference from two timestamps, as mentioned before, is pretty straight forward.

But in my situation I needed to maintain two things:

1) The format 00:00:00 for the column Total_Downtime in **Table 1**, which changed to an integer value when using DATEDIFF

2) The pivot table Total_Downtime column format [h]:mm:ss (suggested by TobyLL) in excel, which required several calculations to convert from seconds

**Solution**

After learning that every time I copied from **Table 1** to **Table 2** the computed value (e.g. 00:02:00) changed to 1900-01-01 00:02:00.000 and that when imported to Excel it equaled to 1.001388889, I decided to force the "Date" part of the time stamp to be 1899-12-31 so that Excel would only calculate the Grand total in the pivot table with the "Time" (decimal) part.